# Issue with zookeeper and public/vritual IP in azure cloud

Tags: azure, apache-zookeeper

I have the problem that I'm running zookeeper on a virtual server inside the azure cloud. 
Those virtual servers have 2 IP addresses: 1. Public static virtual IP (loadbalancer) that they cannot bind to and 2. an internal IP that sadly gets changed if your machine gets shutdown.

The servers of my cluster that reside outside of the azure cloud use the domain name of the azure servers to connect to them.

I had the zookeeper servers bind to the internal IP (in zoo.cfg) because i didn't know that it would change. How can i setup the zoo.cfg to bind to the current address of an interface or what would be the best solution to deal with the possibly changing internal addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at using public Reserved IP addresses which may help (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/).

You can also assign static private IP addresses - see this script for an example: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23447.how-to-assign-a-private-static-ip-to-an-azure-vm.aspx.  Note that you'll need a setup a private Virtual Network to achieve this.